# compose can not test Dialog

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I have dialog in compose:

```
@Composable
fun testgtt() {
    val saveDialogState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Button(onClick = { saveDialogState.value = true }, modifier = Modifier.testTag(PLACE_TAG)) {
        Text(text = "helllow")
    }

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { saveDialogState.value = false }) {
        Text(text = "helllow",modifier = Modifier.testTag(BUTTON_TAG))
    }
}
```

and want to test it:

```
    @Test
    fun das(){
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            TerTheme {
                testgtt()
            }
        }
        composeTestRule.onRoot(useUnmergedTree = true).printToLog("currentLabelExists")
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(PLACE_TAG).performClick()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(BUTTON_TAG).assertIsDisplayed()
    }
```

but I get this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed: assertExists.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but found '2' nodes that satisfy: (isRoot)
Nodes found:
1) Node #1 at (l=0.0, t=0.0, r=206.0, b=126.0)px
Has 1 child
2) Node #78 at (l=0.0, t=0.0, r=116.0, b=49.0)px
Has 1 child
```

Inspite of the fact that I see the Dialog itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use navigation component:

```
@Composable
fun de(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(navController, "home", Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            composable("home") {
                // This content fills the area provided to the NavHost
                val saveDialogState = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
                Button(onClick = {
                                 navController.navigate("detail_dialog")
                }, modifier = Modifier.testTag(PLACE_TAG)) {
                    Text(text = "helllow")
                }
            }
            dialog("detail_dialog") {
                // This content will be automatically added to a Dialog() composable
                // and appear above the HomeScreen or other composable destinations
                
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = {navController.navigate("home")}) {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
//                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
            elevation = 8.dp
        ){
        Text(text = "helllow", modifier = Modifier.testTag(BUTTON_TAG))
        }
    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this error is the line: `composeTestRule.onRoot(useUnmergedTree = true).printToLog("currentLabelExists")`

`onRoot` expects a single node, but i suspect both the containing view and the dialog each return their own root (Speculation)

A possible workaround is to instead print both root trees using something like
`composeTestRule.onAllNodes(isRoot()).printToLog("currentLabelExists")`

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer** : Use `onAllNodesWithText` sach as following :

```
onAllNodesWithText("Your Text")[0].assertIsDisplayed()
onAllNodesWithText("Your Text")[1].assertIsDisplayed()
```

**Details:**

According to [here](https://akjaw.com/wiriting-ui-tests-for-pager-layouts-jetpack-compose/) this error happens when we have ***tow (or more) text or tag*** inside the Composable functions...You can check it with this:

```
onRoot(useUnmergedTree = true).printToLog("TAG")
```

Answer (score 2):

As @DanielO said you can use the `isRoot()` selector, see below. That however prints out the same message as before.

> A possible workaround is to instead print both root trees using something like
> `composeTestRule.onAllNodes(isRoot()).printToLog("currentLabelExists")`

You have to distinctivly select which root you are looking for. By using the selectors:

- `.get( index )`
- `.onFirst()`
- `.onLast()`

When added it should look like this:

- `composeTestRule.onAllNodes(isRoot()).get(1).printToLog("T:")`
- `composeTestRule.onAllNodes(isRoot()).onFirst().printToLog("T:")`
- `composeTestRule.onAllNodes(isRoot()).onLast().printToLog("T:")`

Comment: Or `[<index>]`: `composeTestRule.onAllNodesWithText("text"))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same situation where i need to click a button in a dialog in compose. In compose testing [cheat sheet](https://developer.android.com/static/images/jetpack/compose/compose-testing-cheatsheet.png) they have this matcher call isDialog(), using this you can test the dialog in your UI tests.

Sample test

```html
composeTestRule.onNode(
            isDialog()
                    and
                    hasAnyDescendant(
                        hasText("ok", ignoreCase = true)
                    ),
            useUnmergedTree = true
        ).performClick()
```